# Gcloud command for listing notification channels not working with filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to filter the existing channels created for stack-driver alert notifications using `gcloud` command based on the **displayName**. The channels are of type emails and webhook and below is structure of email notification channel:

```
creationRecord:
  mutateTime: '2021-03-16T14:28:59.926805618Z'
displayName: 'Test Notifications Channel'
enabled: true
labels:
  email_address: 1234fcb0.XXXPortal.onmicrosoft.com@ayd.teams.ms
mutationRecords:
- mutateTime: '2021-03-16T14:28:59.926805618Z'
name: projects/xxx/notificationChannels/13657854696054677020
type: email
```

I am using the following Gcloud command to list this channel to find out whether it actually exists.

```
gcloud alpha monitoring channels list --filter='displayName="Test Notifications Channel"' --format='value(name)' --project=xxx
```

The output is:

> WARNING: The following filter keys were not present in any resource : displayName

Also the **beta** version of the command gives the same result. I need to find out if the channel exists and by the **displayName**.

**Note:** in the --filter='type="email"' is working, but I don't require that.

Which gcloud command and filter can I use to solve this issue?

### Update

Thanks for your responses below, i find that the filter is indeed working for the above code, as rightly pointed out there is some trailing space. What I have been actually trying is the
the **displayName** is consisting of **Test Notifications Channel Default**.

But in the filter I have given only, omitting the Default:

```
gcloud alpha monitoring channels list --filter='displayName="Test Notifications Channel"' --format='value(name)' --project=xxx
```

but my requirement is to print all the channels starting with the **displayName** Test Notifications Channel so I want something like this:

```
gcloud alpha monitoring channels list --filter='displayName="Test Notifications Channel*"' --format='value(name)' --project=xxx
```

Comment: Make sure that you use correct project name, the only way i was able to reproduce the issue is if I provided the existing but incorrect project name.

Comment: I think @jabbson has the explanation. Also, from your question, the `displayName` appears to include a trailing space that is not included in the equality filter.

Comment: @DazWilkin, you are correct

Comment: I am not aware of an operator for "starts with", but there is one for "contains". Try `displayName:"Test Notification Channel"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gcloud alpha monitoring channels list --filter='displayName:"Test Notifications Channel"' --format='value(name)' --project=xxx
```

This command gives all the Test Notifications like:

**Test Notifications Channel Default**

**Test Notifications Channel Non-Default**

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the channel details using below command

```
gcloud beta monitoring channels list
```

For your specific use case

```
gcloud beta monitoring channels list --filter='displayName:"Test Notifications Channel"' --format='value(name)' --project=xxx
```

Reference :

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-channels-api#api-list-channels